# Achieve 3 days moving average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble with a task in SQL Server. The name of the table is 'test'.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    [entry_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL,
)

INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-01', 10, 1);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-02', 20, 2);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-03', 10, 1);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-04', 30, 2);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-05', 10, 1);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 11, 3);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 40, 1);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-07', 10, 2);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-08', 50, 3);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-09', 10, 2);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 60, 2);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 50, 4);
INSERT test VALUES ( '2012-02-11', 51, 3);
```

Based on above data, I want get output like below:

```
   entry_date |value |id |averagevaluesof_3days
-----------+------+---+----------------------
2012-02-01 |10    |1  | 0       -----here we donot have last3rdaysdate
2012-02-03 |10    |1  | 6.6-------last 3days feb3 and feb2 and feb1
2012-02-05 |10    |1  | 6.6
2012-02-06 |40    |1  | 0 ----here we donot have last3rdaysdate(4th date is missed)
2012-02-02 |20    |2  | 0
2012-02-04 |30    |2  | 16.6
2012-02-07 |10    |2  | 0
2012-02-09 |10    |2  | 6.6
2012-02-10 |60    |2  | 0
2012-02-06 |11    |3  | 0
2012-02-08 |50    |3  | 20.3
2012-02-11 |51    |3  | 0
2012-02-10 |50    |4  | 0
```

I need to calculate the average values of the running last three days of information at date (entry_date) based on id wise.

if entry_date do not have last 3rd day of information at date (entry_date) then consider that dates average 0.

Let me provide an example further explaining my goal:

```
 here we need to consider based on id wise
 if we consider id=1 related information

- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-01`, this date have value and back 2 days don't have value less than 2012-02-01 average value is 0 

- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-03`, this date have value and back 2 days means 2012-02-01 and 2012-01-02. Here we can take 3 days average for 2012-02-03 date is 6.6 ((10+0+10)/3 =6.6) if we take 2012-02-05 is 6.6 ((10+0+10)/3 = 6.6)
- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-01`, this date have value and back 2 days don't have value less than 2012-02-01 average value is 0 

if we consider id=2 related information
- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-02`, this date have value and back 2 days means 2012-02-01 and 2012-01-31,don't have value then average value is 0
- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-04`, this date have value and back 2 days means 2012-02-03 and 2012-02-02. Here we can take 3 days average for 2012-02-04 date is 16.6 ((30+0+20)/3 =16.6) if we take 2012-02-07 is 0 because of last 3rd date dont have

- If the `Entry_date: 2012-02-09`, this date have value and back 2 days means 2012-02-08 and 2012-02-07. Here we can take 3 days average for 2012-02-09 date is 6.6 ((10+0+10)/3 =6.6) if we take 2012-02-10 is 0 because of last 3rd date dont have
```

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task for SQL Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Please leave only one relevant tag. Is it possible that some dates are missing in your table? Please extend you example with three rows with dates `2012-02-17`, `2012-02-18`, `2012-02-19` and show us how the result should look like.

Comment: what about `2012-02-10`? There are 2 same date?

Comment: @ravikumar: Please check my answer.

Comment: need to get average values based on ids wise ,when consider ids corresponding data donot have last3rdday date then consider that date average is 0.if 1st and 3rd day date have then consider average values.if not then consider average value is zero

Comment: Your data and description does not match. This makes it very confusing. e.g. There is no data for id 1 on 2012-02-02 so how can you have an average for id 1 on 2012-02-03. Based on your `INSERT` statements, all averages should be 0 since there are no id with 3 consecutive dates.

Comment: yes, id 1 is do not have this date 2012-02-02 .as per this data we need consider 1st and 3rd dates available or not .if available then consider average values of 2days value/3. if not available then consider average is 0.some time we may have 3 consecutive dates that time get average 3 days value/3

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
   SELECT x.entry_date
    ,x.value
    ,x.id
    ,convert(DECIMAL(18, 2), CASE 
            WHEN (
                    SELECT count(*)
                    FROM test
                    WHERE id = x.id
                        AND entry_date <= (x.entry_date)
                    ) >= 3
                THEN avg(value) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id
                            ,entry_date rows BETWEEN 2 preceding
                                AND CURRENT row
                        )
            ELSE 0
            END) AS rollingavg
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,entry_date
        ,convert(DECIMAL(18, 2), sum(value)) AS value
    FROM test
    GROUP BY id
        ,entry_date
    ) x
```

Comment: This should be the fastest solution.

Comment: You are missing an `AND DATEDIFF(day, entry_date, x.entry_date) < 3` in the inner select count(*). Currently it ignores gaps in the dates.

Comment: @Ravikumar: Please select the answer that best suits you.

Comment: I am getting expected result based on above query. example: id=1 and date=2012-02-03 expected movingavg3days values is 6.6 but this result show 0. if  this date 2012-02-03  back feb2nd and feb1st,here feb2nd donot have data then consider 0 for 2nd date and 1stdate have data finally 10+0+10/3=6.6 .another date is 2012-02-06 here we have 5thdate have data but donot have 4th date then 6thdate position average consider 0.mainly we need to consider 1st and 3rd day related dates have or not if have then consider avg value if not then keep zero. please tell me how to achieve this task

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    CREATE table #test
(
    [entry_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL
)

INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-01', 10, 1);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-02', 20, 2);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-03', 10, 1);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-04', 30, 2);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-05', 10, 1);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 11, 3);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-06', 40, 1);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-07', 10, 2);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-08', 50, 3);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-09', 10, 2);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 60, 2);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-10', 50, 4);
INSERT #test VALUES ( '2012-02-11', 51, 3);

SELECT              
    CurrentRow.entry_date,
    CurrentRow.value,
    CurrentRow.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(PriviousRow1.value, 0) = 0 OR
             ISNULL(PriviousRow2.value, 0) = 0 THEN 0.00
        ELSE 
            (ISNULL(CurrentRow.value, 0) +
             ISNULL(PriviousRow1.value, 0) +
             ISNULL(PriviousRow2.value, 0)) / 3.0 END averagevaluesof_3days

FROM
    #test CurrentRow LEFT JOIN 
    #test PriviousRow1 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -1, CurrentRow.entry_date), 112) = 
                          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PriviousRow1.entry_date, 112) LEFT JOIN 
    #test PriviousRow2 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -2, CurrentRow.entry_date), 112) = 
                          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PriviousRow2.entry_date, 112)
ORDER BY 
    CurrentRow.entry_date
```

Result:

```
entry_date      value       id          averagevaluesof_3days
----------      ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
2012-02-01      10          1           0.00
2012-02-02      20          2           0.00
2012-02-03      10          1           13.33
2012-02-04      30          2           20.00
2012-02-05      10          1           16.66
2012-02-06      11          3           17.00
2012-02-06      40          1           26.66
2012-02-07      10          2           10.33
2012-02-07      10          2           20.00
2012-02-08      50          3           23.66
2012-02-08      50          3           33.33
2012-02-09      10          2           23.33
2012-02-10      60          2           40.00
2012-02-10      50          4           36.66
2012-02-11      51          3           40.33
2012-02-11      51          3           37.00
```

Comment: Note: Your sample data and expected data is not matched.